# Free Music CD Catalog Software

Tags: windows-7, compact-disc, music-management

I'm looking for a free/open source music CD cataloging software that will help manage my CD collection. Ideally, it will be able to pull metadata about the discs from the Internet so that I wouldn't have to type it all into the program manually. If it can scan a drive and locate music files to add to its database, that would be a plus, but not absolutely necessary.

Here's an example of what I'm looking for, although this program is for DVDs only: http://dvdchief.com/

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It might not be fully what you are looking for, but for all kinds of collections I recommend GCstar:

http://www.gcstar.org/

It has options to fetch metadata for movies, books and CD's, and you can create your own database models if a template does not fit your needs. Cross-platform as well.